# how to control the limits of two variables in manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This is my code.

```
myPlot[a_, b_] := ParametricPlot3D[Sin[x], {x, a, b}];

Manipulate[Show[myPlot[a, b]], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

I want to manipulate `a,b`, so that the entire plot will change as we change `a,b`. 
However there are errors. Do you know how to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

```
myPlot[a_, b_] := ParametricPlot3D[{1, x, Sin[x]}, {x, a, b}];

Manipulate[Show[myPlot[a, b]], {{a, -1}, -1, Pi}, {{b, 1}, -1, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

The errors occur whenever `a==b` since the domain of the plot is just a point which is not allowed. Consequently, you must handle `a==b` as a special case. It also helps to fix the `PlotRange`.

```
myPlot[a_, b_] := ParametricPlot3D[
   {1, x, Sin[x]}, {x, a, b},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, Pi}, {-1, 1}}];

Manipulate[
 Piecewise[{
   {Graphics3D[
     Point[{1, a, Sin[a]}],
     Axes -> True,
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, Pi}, {-1, 1}}],
    a == b}},
  myPlot[a, b]],
 {{a, -1}, -1, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1}, -1, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]